# Airflow Can't Connect to SFTP with SSH Private Key

Tags: python, airflow, sftp

I am trying to use the SFTP Operator/Hook with a SSH private key instead of a password.

My connection has the following extra arguments: `{"key_file": "/home/airflow/key_files/some_key", "no_host_key_check": "true"}`. My SSH Private key looks like the following:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now when I try to create a hook I get the following error:

```
>>> from airflow.contrib.hooks.sftp_hook import SFTPHook
>>> s = SFTPHook(ftp_conn_id='my_sftp_connection')
[2020-07-08 13:40:25,449] {base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: my_sftp_connection. Host: my_sftp.com, Port: 22, Schema: None, Login: user, Password: None, extra: {'key_file': '/home/airflow/key_files/some_key', 'no_host_key_check': 'true'}
[2020-07-08 13:40:25,452] {base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: my_sftp_connection. Host: my_sftp.com, Port: 22, Schema: None, Login: user, Password: None, extra: {'key_file': '/home/airflow/key_files/some_key', 'no_host_key_check': 'true'}
>>> s.list_directory('/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 167, in _set_authentication
    private_key_file, private_key_pass)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 206, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 279, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 289, in _read_private_key
    raise SSHException("not a valid " + tag + " private key file")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py", line 151, in list_directory
    conn = self.get_conn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py", line 114, in get_conn
    self.conn = pysftp.Connection(**conn_params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    self._set_authentication(password, private_key, private_key_pass)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 171, in _set_authentication
    private_key_file, private_key_pass)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 206, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 224, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("DSA", filename, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 279, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 289, in _read_private_key
    raise SSHException("not a valid " + tag + " private key file")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid DSA private key file
```

What am I doing wrong here? That same SSH key works with WINSCP and the SFTP command in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I upgraded that paramiko library and now it appears to be working. Will leave this as unanswered in case there was something else I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, except that I'm using Composer, which is Airflow-based managed service in Google Cloud and I do not use the SFTP `contrib` operator.
Instead I use the `apache-airflow-backport-providers-sftp` which is backported from Airflow 2.0 and is compatible with my Airflow environment, which is 1.10.14.

It works fine with a user/password, but fails with an RSA key.

The contrib operator and the provider package are equivalent, and depend on the same Python modules: `paramiko`, `pysftp`, and `sshtunnel`.

My `pip freeze`:

```
paramiko==2.7.2 (latest release)
pysftp==0.2.9 (latest release)
sshtunnel==0.1.5 (latest release is 0.4.0)
```

In my understanding, and following your description, the problem is not in the top module (contrib or provider). You said that the problem is in `paramiko` but it works fine for me with the SSH operator and a RSA key. So, maybe it is in `pysftp`...

I am lost here.